# Column does not exist in UNION ALL query

Tags: postgresql

I am doing some code for my badminton club.

**Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE School (
    Name text PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Tournament (
    Number integer PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Player (
    Name text NOT NULL,
    SchoolName text NOT NULL,
    Gender text CHECK (Gender IN ('Masculin', 'Féminin'))
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY Player
    ADD CONSTRAINT Player_pkey PRIMARY KEY (name, SchoolName);

ALTER TABLE ONLY Player
    ADD CONSTRAINT SchoolName_fkey FOREIGN KEY (SchoolName) REFERENCES School(Name);

CREATE TABLE Result (
    -- PlayerId_fkey text
    PlayerName_fkey text,
    SchoolName_fkey text,
    Category text CHECK (Category IN ('Benjamin', 'Cadet', 'Juvénile')),
    TournamentNumber integer,
    Score integer,
    TypeOfPlay text CHECK (TypeOfPlay IN ('Simple', 'Double'))
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY Result
    ADD CONSTRAINT PlayerName_fkey FOREIGN KEY (PlayerName_fkey, SchoolName_fkey) REFERENCES Player(Name, SchoolName);    

ALTER TABLE ONLY Result
    ADD CONSTRAINT TournamentNumber_fkey FOREIGN KEY (TournamentNumber) REFERENCES Tournament(Number);
```

**Query**

```
-- Select each player with their single and double total score
SELECT PlayerName_fkey, ScoreSimple, ScoreDouble

FROM ( 
    -- Select the sum of the best results for each player in single play
    SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank, SUM(score) as ScoreSimple 
    FROM (
        -- Select the best four results in the season for each player in single play
        SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber, rank() over (PARTITION BY PlayerName_fkey order by Score desc) AS ScoreRank 
        FROM (
            -- Select, for each player, the score for each tournament they played in single play
            SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, TournamentNumber 
                 FROM Result LEFT JOIN Player ON Player.name=Result.PlayerName_fkey 
                 WHERE Category='Benjamin' AND Gender='Féminin' AND TypeOfPlay='Simple' AND score > 0 ) tBestIndividualScoresWithDuplicates 
            GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber) tBestIndividualScores
        WHERE ScoreRank <= 4 
        GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank 

    UNION ALL 

    -- Select the sum of the best results for each player in double play
    SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank, SUM(score) as ScoreDouble 
    FROM (
        -- Select the best four results in the season for each player in double play
        SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber, rank() over (PARTITION BY PlayerName_fkey order by Score desc) AS ScoreRank 
        FROM ( 
            -- Select, for each player, the score for each tournament they played in double play
            SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, TournamentNumber 
                 FROM Result LEFT JOIN Player ON Player.name=Result.PlayerName_fkey 
                 WHERE Category='Benjamin' AND Gender='Féminin' AND TypeOfPlay='Double' AND score > 0 ) tBestIndividualScoresWithDuplicates 
            GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber) tBestIndividualScores
        WHERE ScoreRank <= 4 
        GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank) t1
```

**Question**

The problem I have is I get the error: "column "scoredouble" does not exist". How do I get the scoredouble column display on my first query? I cannot use a JOIN because some players have scores in one type of play (singles or double) and not the other.

Link here: http://rextester.com/XIG14273

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49306/discussion-on-question-by-benoit-goderre-column-does-not-exist-in-union-all-quer).

Answer (score 1):

With the help of many people whom gave me a lot of help, I finally got a working solution:

```
SELECT PlayerName_fkey, SumScoresSimpleTotal, SumScoresDoubleTotal, SumScoresTotal, rank() over (order by SumScoresTotal desc) AS OverallRank 

FROM (

    SELECT COALESCE(t1.PlayerName_fkey, t2.PlayerName_fkey) as PlayerName_fkey, coalesce(SumScoresSimple, 0) as SumScoresSimpleTotal, coalesce(SumScoresDouble,0) as SumScoresDoubleTotal, 
    (coalesce(SumScoresSimple, 0) + coalesce(SumScoresDouble, 0)) as SumScoresTotal 
    FROM (

    SELECT PlayerName_fkey, ScoreSimple, sum(ScoreSimple) over (partition by PlayerName_fkey) as SumScoresSimple

    FROM (

        SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank, SUM(score) as ScoreSimple 
        FROM (
            -- Select the best four results in the season for each player in single play
            SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber, rank() over (PARTITION BY PlayerName_fkey order by Score desc) AS ScoreRank 
            FROM (
                -- Select, for each player, the score for each tournament they played in single play
                SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, TournamentNumber 
                     FROM Result LEFT JOIN Player ON Player.name=Result.PlayerName_fkey 
                     WHERE Category='Juvénile' AND Gender='Féminin' AND TypeOfPlay='Simple' AND score > 0 ) tBestIndividualScoresWithDuplicates 
                GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber) tBestIndividualScores
        WHERE ScoreRank <= 4 
        GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank)tinside1) t1

        FULL OUTER JOIN

    (SELECT PlayerName_fkey, ScoreDouble, sum(ScoreDouble) over (partition by PlayerName_fkey) as SumScoresDouble

    FROM (

        SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank, SUM(score) as ScoreDouble
        FROM (
            -- Select the best four results in the season for each player in single play
            SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber, rank() over (PARTITION BY PlayerName_fkey order by Score desc) AS ScoreRank 
            FROM (
                -- Select, for each player, the score for each tournament they played in single play
                SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, TournamentNumber 
                     FROM Result LEFT JOIN Player ON Player.name=Result.PlayerName_fkey 
                     WHERE Category='Juvénile' AND Gender='Féminin' AND TypeOfPlay='Double' AND score > 0 ) tBestIndividualScoresWithDuplicates 
                GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber) tBestIndividualScores
        WHERE ScoreRank <= 4 
        GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank) tinside2) t2

    ON t1.PlayerName_fkey = t2.PlayerName_fkey

    GROUP BY t1.PlayerName_fkey, t2.PlayerName_fkey, SumScoresSimple, SumScoresDouble

    ORDER BY SumScoresTotal DESC
```

The colasesce functions are particularly important here to avoid empty entries for both the player names and the scores.

Comment: 6 levels of nesting? There ought to be a simpler solution...

Comment: Possibly, but I am learning :).

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the outer select

```
SELECT PlayerName_fkey, ScoreSimple, ScoreDouble
```

The unioned query has a single column with a single name and based on the error it is defaulting to name of the column in the first query so there is no Score Double column to select in the outer query. Even if it didn't produce an error you wouldn't get the results you want because the sinle and doubles scores are on two different lines in your union and wouldn't show up on a single line in the outter query. You can solve this by Left Joining both the sub-queries to the player table so both columns exist but you get a null if the player doesn't have a single or double score.

This should work.

```
SELECT p.PlayerName_fkey, ScoreSimple, ScoreDouble

FROM Player P
LEFT JOIN 
( -- Select the sum of the best results for each player in single play
SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank, SUM(score) as ScoreSimple 
FROM (
    -- Select the best four results in the season for each player in single play
    SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber, rank() over (PARTITION BY PlayerName_fkey order by Score desc) AS ScoreRank 
    FROM (
        -- Select, for each player, the score for each tournament they played in single play
        SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, TournamentNumber 
             FROM Result LEFT JOIN Player ON Player.name=Result.PlayerName_fkey 
             WHERE Category='Benjamin' AND Gender='Féminin' AND TypeOfPlay='Simple' AND score > 0 ) tBestIndividualScoresWithDuplicates 
        GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber) tBestIndividualScores
    WHERE ScoreRank <= 4 
    GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank ) Single on p.PlayerName_fkey = Single.PlayerName_fkey

LEFT JOIN
(
-- Select the sum of the best results for each player in double play
SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank, SUM(score) as ScoreDouble 
FROM (
    -- Select the best four results in the season for each player in double play
    SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber, rank() over (PARTITION BY PlayerName_fkey order by Score desc) AS ScoreRank 
    FROM ( 
        -- Select, for each player, the score for each tournament they played in double play
        SELECT PlayerName_fkey, score, TournamentNumber 
             FROM Result LEFT JOIN Player ON Player.name=Result.PlayerName_fkey 
             WHERE Category='Benjamin' AND Gender='Féminin' AND TypeOfPlay='Double' AND score > 0 ) tBestIndividualScoresWithDuplicates 
        GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, tournamentNumber) tBestIndividualScores
    WHERE ScoreRank <= 4 
    GROUP BY PlayerName_fkey, score, ScoreRank) Doubles on p.PlayerName_fkey = doubles.PlayerName_fkey
```

There are probably better ways to write this but this was the most straightforward modification to what you already had.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This returns empty values for both Simple and Double columns.